# Cannot install WinMo 6.1 Standard SDK with VS2008 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, sdk, installation

I'm trying to install the Windows Mobile 6.1 Standard SDK Refresh on my Vista SP2 machine.  I have Visual Studio 2008 Professional with SP1.  Everytime I try to install, the installer tells me Visual Studio 2005 Standard SP1+ is required.  There is no option to continue.

Googling this problem I've found many forum posts stating Visual Studio 2008 Professional (not Standard) is required, which I have.  I've seen a couple posts from others using Professional, but no solutions.

The SDK installed fine on my XP SP3 laptop.  Is this a Vista issue?  Or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I hadn't installed the Smart Device option during Visual Studio setup.  I installed that and I was able to continue.